# Select rows containing certain values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe whose entries are all strings:

```
   A     B      C
1 apple  banana pear
2 pear   pear   apple
3 banana pear   pear
4 apple  apple  pear
```

etc. I want to select all the rows that contain a certain string, say, 'banana'. I don't know which column it will appear in each time. Of course, I can write a for loop and iterate over all rows. But is there an easier or faster way to do this?

Comment: You can also just do `df[df.values == 'banana']`

Comment: @JoeT.Boka, that gives me a row for every match, so if a row has two 'banana' values, I get two rows with the same index. Not something that can't be handled, but it does require further handling.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Introduction

At the heart of selecting rows, we would need a 1D mask or a pandas-series of boolean elements of length same as length of `df`, let's call it `mask`. So, finally with `df[mask]`, we would get the selected rows off `df` following [boolean-indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Here's our starting `df` :

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
        A       B      C
1   apple  banana   pear
2    pear    pear  apple
3  banana    pear   pear
4   apple   apple   pear
```

#### I. Match one string

Now, if we need to match just one string, it's straight-foward with elementwise equality :

```
In [42]: df == 'banana'
Out[42]: 
       A      B      C
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
3   True  False  False
4  False  False  False
```

If we need to look `ANY` one match in each row, use `.any` method :

```
In [43]: (df == 'banana').any(axis=1)
Out[43]: 
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

To select corresponding rows :

```
In [44]: df[(df == 'banana').any(axis=1)]
Out[44]: 
        A       B     C
1   apple  banana  pear
3  banana    pear  pear
```

---

#### II. Match multiple strings

**1. Search for `ANY` match**

Here's our starting `df` :

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
        A       B      C
1   apple  banana   pear
2    pear    pear  apple
3  banana    pear   pear
4   apple   apple   pear
```

NumPy's [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) would work here (or use pandas.isin as listed in other posts) to get all matches from the list of search strings in `df`. So, say we are looking for `'pear'` or `'apple'` in `df` :

```
In [51]: np.isin(df, ['pear','apple'])
Out[51]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])

# ANY match along each row
In [52]: np.isin(df, ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1)
Out[52]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True])

# Select corresponding rows with masking
In [56]: df[np.isin(df, ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1)]
Out[56]: 
        A       B      C
1   apple  banana   pear
2    pear    pear  apple
3  banana    pear   pear
4   apple   apple   pear
```

**2. Search for `ALL` match**

Here's our starting `df` again :

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
        A       B      C
1   apple  banana   pear
2    pear    pear  apple
3  banana    pear   pear
4   apple   apple   pear
```

So, now we are looking for rows that have `BOTH` say `['pear','apple']`. We will make use of `NumPy-broadcasting` :

```
In [66]: np.equal.outer(df.to_numpy(copy=False),  ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1)
Out[66]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

So, we have a search list of `2` items and hence we have a 2D mask with `number of rows = len(df)` and `number of cols = number of search items`. Thus, in the above result, we have the first col for `'pear'` and second one for `'apple'`.

To make things concrete, let's get a mask for three items `['apple','banana', 'pear']` :

```
In [62]: np.equal.outer(df.to_numpy(copy=False),  ['apple','banana', 'pear']).any(axis=1)
Out[62]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

The columns of this mask are for `'apple','banana', 'pear'` respectively.

Back to `2` search items case, we had earlier :

```
In [66]: np.equal.outer(df.to_numpy(copy=False),  ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1)
Out[66]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Since, we are looking for `ALL` matches in each row :

```
In [67]: np.equal.outer(df.to_numpy(copy=False),  ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1).all(axis=1)
Out[67]: array([ True,  True, False,  True])
```

Finally, select rows :

```
In [70]: df[np.equal.outer(df.to_numpy(copy=False),  ['pear','apple']).any(axis=1).all(axis=1)]
Out[70]: 
       A       B      C
1  apple  banana   pear
2   pear    pear  apple
4  apple   apple   pear
```

Comment: Actually this is easier to use when searching for multiple strings

Answer (score 25):

For single search value

```
df[df.values  == "banana"]
```

or

```
 df[df.isin(['banana'])]
```

For multiple search terms:

```
  df[(df.values  == "banana")|(df.values  == "apple" ) ]
```

or

```
df[df.isin(['banana', "apple"])]

  #         A       B      C
  #  1   apple  banana    NaN
  #  2     NaN     NaN  apple
  #  3  banana     NaN    NaN
  #  4   apple   apple    NaN
```

From Divakar: lines with both are returned.

```
select_rows(df,['apple','banana'])

 #         A       B     C
 #   0  apple  banana  pear
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want all the rows of `df` that contain **any** of the values in `values`, use:

```py
df[df.isin(values).any(1)]
```

---

Example:

```
In [2]: df                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 
   0  1  2
0  7  4  9
1  8  2  7
2  1  9  7
3  3  8  5
4  5  1  1

In [3]: df[df.isin({1, 9, 123}).any(1)]                                                                                          
Out[3]: 
   0  1  2
0  7  4  9
2  1  9  7
4  5  1  1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a boolean mask from comparing the entire df against your string and call `dropna` passing param `how='all'` to drop rows where your string doesn't appear in all cols:

```
In [59]:
df[df == 'banana'].dropna(how='all')

Out[59]:
        A       B    C
1     NaN  banana  NaN
3  banana     NaN  NaN
```

To test for multiple values you can use multiple masks:

```
In [90]:
banana = df[(df=='banana')].dropna(how='all')
banana

Out[90]:
        A       B    C
1     NaN  banana  NaN
3  banana     NaN  NaN

In [91]:    
apple = df[(df=='apple')].dropna(how='all')
apple

Out[91]:
       A      B      C
1  apple    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN  apple
4  apple  apple    NaN
```

You can use `index.intersection` to index just the common index values:

```
In [93]:
df.loc[apple.index.intersection(banana.index)]

Out[93]:
       A       B     C
1  apple  banana  pear
```

Comment: Thank you. This certainly works if I'm looking for one string. What if I want to select rows that contain both 'banana' and 'apple'?

Comment: I don't know pandas, but maybe something like that : `df[df == 'banana', 'apple'].dropna(how='all')`?

Comment: @Andromedae93 That gives me a TypeError

Comment: @mcglashan I never used pandas, but `isin` function should work. Documentation : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: see updated answer, you can't use `isin` because you will get multiple positives if for instance you have 2 apples but no bananas

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a single line solution for it.

Comment: @shivsn not without defining some user `func` like divikar's answer or wrapping my answer into a func

Comment: Great answer, but I wonder if `df[df.values == 'banana']` might be a better solution. It's about 5 X faster. But, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @JoeR pure numpy methods will always be faster but the pandas methods have better type and missing data handling, for this toy example and where the dtype is homogenous then a pure np method is superior

Comment: Yep, I agree. I always like your answers, learning a lot from you. Thanks.