# Searching for bounds that contain value?

Tags: python, search

I have a large number of bounds (2 numbers that define a min and max range) I need an efficient method that I can use to find every bound that contains a value that I am searching for.

```
# generated in some way at runtime
bounds = [[0,10], [30,35], [-1, 2], [-30, 105], [132, 200006]]

# runtime value, not a constant
value = 45


for bound in bounds:
    if value >= bound[0] and value <= bound[1]:
        # do something with value
```

This above code shows what I need, but it is extremely inefficient and I need to run millions of times. I've tried using some sort of BSP, but when the bounds overlap it doesn't work out that well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185688/select-rows-containing-certain-values-from-pandas-dataframe may be a place to start.

Comment: Have you tried anything?, show us what you got

Comment: Can't be that difficult. Make an attempt and you will get it. If you are using `range` object, you can use attributes `start`, `stop` and `step`.

Comment: @arvindpdmn Creating one that runs in linear time isn't difficult, but I need it to be more efficient than that. As I have thousands to millions of ranges

Answer (score 1):

A range is a generator and does not have anything. But you can use 'in'

```
>>> r = range(2,20)
>>> 3 in r
```

Comment: "A range is a generator" — only in python 3

Comment: I have multiple ranges though, and going through each one is inefficient as there are numerous of them.

Comment: I see you added example code. That looks indeed very efficient.

Now assuming that you need to keep your bounds somehow you could at least create some 'general bound' too.

first you have [0,10], that's a general bound too.
you add [30,35], there is no overlap, you have two 'general bounds'.
now you add [-1, 2], this overlaps with the first one so you replace [0,10] with [-1, 10]. [-30, 105], [132, 200006]

Comment: I have to practive formatting in this comment format :-( I'll try again

[0,10] gives a genral bound, [30,35], too 

[-1, 2] overlaps with the first one so you replace that one with [-1, 10]

 [-30, 105] contains both the first and the second one so now you have one upper and lower bound left

[132, 200006] has no overlap.

If you work with upper and lower bounds, I would go for this. Otherwise just create a list or set with all values - it all depends on your problem space.

Answer (score 0):

```
def valFinder(seq , number):
  if number in seq:
    return True
  return False


print( valFinder( range(1,10) , 5 ) ) 
>> True
print( valFinder( range(10,15) , 5 ) ) 
>> False
```