# Keyword search in a large CSV file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I wonder if there is a way to search a list of keywords using Python. I am able to search though my data using PostgreSQL. Here is my PostgreSQL code

```
SELECT distinct ON (id) id, year, cost, description
FROM mydata
WHERE description similar to'%((hotel)||(travel)|(taxi)|(food))%';
```

I don't know if Python is the best way to do it, but the work that I am replicating uses Python and would like to stick with Python.

I was able to search one keyword but am not sure how to do multiple.

```
 import csv
 with open('mydata.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'food' in line:
            print(line)
```

I need help with

1) searching using multiple keywords

2) way to export the data back to csv

Comment: Assuming you have a reasonable amount of data to search, pandas would be an easy/efficient way to import, search, and export. Basics: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html. Here's an answer that specifically addressed what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185688/select-rows-containing-certain-values-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
> import pandas as pd
```

multiple keyword search using contains

```
> df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
> df[df.description.str.contains('hotel|travel|taxi|food')]
```

Export to csv

```
> df.to_csv('new.csv')
```