# How to filter rows that contain specific text from entire DataFame and not just one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

| Name | Name | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Ron | Bob | Ron |
| Ron | Bob | Ron | Adam |
| Ron | Ron | Adam | Kelly |

I want to create a filter that will return all of the rows that contain the name "Bob". Other suggestions for a problem like this specify a column to look for the word Bob, but I need it to check the entire dataframe for the name Bob and return the rows that contain the word Bob in any of the columns. Like so,

| Name | Name | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Ron | Bob | Ron |
| Ron | Bob | Ron | Adam |

As you can see, I only want the rows that contain the name Bob in any of its columns.

I do not want to need to specify what column the code should look into because the column names can change. Is there a way to do this without writing out every column name into the code and simply have it check the entire dataframe?

Comment: `df[df.eq('Bob').any(axis=1)]` Explanation in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186202/15497888) under "I. Match one string"